# Hilbert space operator associated to gauge transformation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, field-theory, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance

Suppose we have a Lagrangian that with fields that are acted on by a symmetry group, e.g. $$\mathcal{L} = \partial_{\mu}\phi \partial^{\mu}\phi^* - m^2 \phi \phi^*$$ with $G=U(1)$ (i.e. $\phi \to e^{i \alpha}\phi$). Then this symmetry group has a representation acting on the physical Hilbert space - to find these operators we can use [Noether's first theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem) to find a conserved current and integrate to get a conserved charge operator $\hat{Q}$ and then a representation of $U(1)$ by acting on the Hilbert space with $\hat{U} = e^{i \theta \hat{Q}}$.

**My question** now is what happens if we now have a gauge symmetry $G$ - how do we find the Hilbert space operator corresponding to gauge symmetries $G$? We can no longer use Noether's first theorem. (Of course we expect that the subspace of physical states will transform as a singlet under the Hilbert space operators corresponding to elements of $G$.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question, but [Noether's second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_second_theorem) is the analog of Noether's ("first") theorem for gauge symmetries.  For a field $A_\mu$ with a gauge symmetry $A_\mu \to A_\mu + \partial_\mu \lambda$, the conserved current (which is also the generator of gauge transformations) is given by $J^\mu = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial A_\mu}|_{A_\mu = 0}$.  In the case of QED, $J_\mu = e \bar{\Psi} \gamma_\mu \Psi$, where the $\Psi$ are the electron Dirac fermion operators.

Comment: Note that in a sense this is more of a math identity than a physical identity, in the sense that unlike the Noether current for a global symmetry, the conservation of a gauge current is purely an operator identity, and does not require making any assumptions about whether or not the action is extremized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'm aware of Noether's second theorem but I'm still not entirely sure how we can then get an operator on the Hilbert space corresponding to a gauge transformation?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Dirac conjecture](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=Dirac+conjecture+gauge+first+class+constraints), in the Hamiltonian and canonical formulation of [gauge theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory), the gauge transformations are generated by [first class constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint).  In the case of QED, the gauge generator is the Gauss law operator ${\bf \nabla}\cdot {\bf E}-\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$.

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit about what exactly you mean by "the Gauss law operator?"

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that to impose gauge symmetry by Dirac's conjecture we insist the physical states are invariant under Gauss' law - however I'm really wondering about the more general case of how do we construct the Hilbert space representation of a spacetime dependent operator - I'd like to see understand how this works even when the group $G$ isn't a symmetry and then specialise to the case where it is and see that states are invariant. Every group action should have a corresponding action on the Hilbert space?